# AJAX POST Request Exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send an AJAX request with a JSON file to my NodeJS server, but it's throwing what looks like a JSON formatting error client side.

**Error Message**

> ```
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0
> at parse (<anonymous>)
> at Nb (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
> at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
> at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
> ```

**Script:**

```
<script>
      function SendToServer() {
        var textToSubmit = document.getElementById("SubmitDataEntry").value;

        var objectData = {
          submittedText: textToSubmit,
          column2: "Mitochondria is the powerhouse of the cell",
        };

        var objectDataString = JSON.stringify(objectData);

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            o: objectDataString,
          },
          success: function (data) {
            alert("Success");
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
            // alert("Error");
          },
        });
      }
 </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>AJAX Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 40px; padding: 50px;">
      <label for="SubmitDataEntry">Submit My Data</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="SubmitDataEntry"
        placeholder="Example input"
      />
      <button onclick="SendToServer()">
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So far, I've checked the JSON I'm trying to send in a linter, and verified that my Node server can receive requests with Insomnia Core. I believe my JQuery import is also working correctly since the error that's firing is from there!

Comment: Don't you just need to submit `data: objectData`? Why are you nesting `objectDataString` into a parent object?

Comment: Have you checked HTTP request in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: I've just fixed it! (Well, kind of) I've just rewrote it to be a lot simpler as 
$.post("/", {
   objectData
        });

Comment: It's weird, with that other version from my post here the data actually does get received by my server yet Jquery still throws that formatting exception in the console

Server's req.body
`code`
{
  objectData: {
    submittedText: '',
    column: 'Mitochondria is the powerhouse of the cell'
  }
}
`code`

Comment: In the case anyone else sees this with the same issue, turns out my POST request handler on my server script was returning something other than JSON as a response! Changing that to JSON resolved the error message.